# Find intersection points of arbitrary BSpline curve

Tags: equation-solving, computational-geometry, splines

I'm researching some computational geometry and am trying to find a method of determining the {x,y} intersection of a circle and BSplineCurve for further processing.

```
basisPoints = {{0, 0}, {3000, 7000}, {4000, -7000}, {5000, 
    7000}, {8000, 0}};
f = BSplineFunction[basisPoints];
p = ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 1}, MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}, 
   Mesh -> {10}, MeshStyle -> {PointSize[0.01], Red}];
points = Cases[Normal[p], _Point, Infinity];
ptsPlus = Point /@ {f[0], f[1]};
points = SortBy[points~Join~ptsPlus, First];

Show[
 ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 1}],
 Graphics[Circle[#, 1400]] & /@ points[[All, 1]],
 Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[9], Red, points}],
 PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

[image]

Most potential solutions I've come across online so far have the curve in a different form. However, for the project we really want to try to use `BSplineCurves` because of their ease of input by other users, making the final curve somewhat arbitrary. Mathematica is great for offering `BSplineFunction` in this regard. Before I go through of all the trouble of translating this curve into a more conventional form, is there a straightforward way to find where this `Circle` and `BSplineFunction` intersect?

[image]

```
cir = Circle[#, 1400] & /@ (Cases[points, Point[x_] :> x, Infinity]);
RegionPlot[{
  cir[[1]] // DiscretizeGraphics ,
  spline // DiscretizeGraphics},
 Frame -> False
 ]
```

Comment: `p` and `coords` are not defined. Looks like `p = ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 1}, MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"},    Mesh -> 10]` and `coords = points[[All, 1]];`?

Comment: I've updated the code. The evaluation should run in a fresh notebook now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p = ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 1}, MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}, Mesh -> 10];
points = Cases[Normal[p], _Point, Infinity];
ptsPlus = Point /@ {f[0], f[1]};
points = SortBy[points~Join~ptsPlus, First];
coords = points[[All, 1]];

circles = Graphics[Circle[#, 1400]] & /@ coords;

intersections = Union @@ (Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[Show[p, #], 
      Graphics`Mesh`AllPoints -> False] & /@ circles);

Show[p, circles, Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[5], Red, Point @ intersections}], 
  PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

```
Show[p, circles[[1]], 
 Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[9], Red, 
   Point@Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[Show[p, circles[[1]]], 
     Graphics`Mesh`AllPoints -> False]}],
 PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 800, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm.. Looking over the post, this is not as straightforward as I thought. I'm at the limits of my knowledge of computational geometry here.  Please bare with me as I run through this code.